# Angular $compile ui-grid for jasmine tests without $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ui-grid

I am trying to do use `$compile` to compile a *ui-grid* for Jasmine testing. It worked fine when I used `$scope` as a passable parameter to the controller. however, I am migrating away to `vm`. This has caused `$compile` to fail when compiling the *ui-grid*.

```
var rootScope = $rootScope;
var controller = $controller('Controller', {stuff: stuff, other: other});
$compile('<div ui-grid="vm.grids.grid1" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-auto-resize></div>')(rootScope);
rootScope.$apply();
```

Doing it this way gives me an error of `cannot read property 'data' of undefined.` when *ui-grid* javascript is being stepped through.

I have also tried passing the controller to $compile, using `controller.grids.grid1` instead, and `rootScope.$digest()` instead of `$apply()`.

Is there something I am missing, or am I going about this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer to my question.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631797/5128309) on a different question helped me get the answer.

```
var rootScope = $rootScope;
var controller = $controller(/**controller stuff**/);
rootScope.vm = controller;
$compile('html to compile')(rootScope);
rootScope.$apply();
```

With this, I was able to get things to compile without using `$scope`.